# Delphi XE5 iPad, application starts in portrait view

Tags: ios, ipad, delphi, orientation, portrait

I'm completing my evaluation of Delphi XE5, which has turned out quite well so far. I've managed a create a rather complex cross-platform app for android and iOS, and to my surprise, it required very few ifdefs.

An important difference that I've found, though, is that Android Apps always respect the current orientation of the device (i.e. they keep the orientation when launched). On my iPad Retina, however, the app always launches in portrait mode, and then rotates to landscape if the device is oriented that way.

I would expect that the app started in whatever orientation is currently active, but I'm surprised it doesn't.

Does anyone have a clue to what could be done to resolve this? It's not a big issue, but it's rather ackward, and certainly not the expected behavior.

Cheers!